# Задача по python "Группа студентов"

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня возникли сложности с задачей по практике, может кто помочь?
Сама задача:

> - объявить пустой список (группа студентов)
> - в список будут добавляться студенты, реализованные в виде словаря следующей структуры {"name" : Ivan, "surname" : Ivanov, "age" : 18}
> - реализовать следующие функции:
>
>   1. Функция добавления студента. Данные вводятся пользователем в консоле.
>   2. Вывод ФИ и возраста студента по введенному в консоле номеру в списке группы в формате:
>        Ivanov Ivan, age = 18
>   3. Вывод всех студентов с возрастом равным XX (возраст вводится в консоле)
>   4. При добавлении студента информация о нем должна построчно записываться в текстовый файл (дополнить функцию
>        №1)
>   5. Прочитать все содержимое файла и вывести на экран

Со списками все работает, но надо это сделать со словарями, а я не понимаю как.

```
class Students(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.group_students = []
        self.filename = f'{name}.txt'

    def add_students(self, data):
        with open(self.filename, 'a') as datafile:
            datafile.write(data + '\n')
        self.group_students.append(data.split())

    def info(self, number):
        number -= 1
        if len(self.group_students) < number < 0:
            print('Нет такого номера в списке')
        else:
            print(*self.group_students[number])

    def selec(self, age):
        for data in self.group_students:
            if data[-1] == age:
                print(*data)

    def fileinfo(self):
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            print(*f.read().split('\n'), sep='\n')


stud = Students(input('введите имя файла для записи ->  '))
print('''выберите действие.
                1 - добавить студента, 2 - вывод по номеру
                3 - вывод по возрасту, 4 - вывод из файла
                для выхода - 0\n''')

while True:

    f = input('Ввод действия:  ')
    if f == '1':
        print('Введите данные через пробел (имя,фамилия,возраст)')
        stud.add_students(input())
    elif f == '2':
        stud.info(int(input('Номер ->  ')))
    elif f == '3':
        stud.selec(input('Возраст-> '))
    elif f == '4':
        stud.fileinfo()
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Накидал пример. Я несколько схитрил, используя для хранения данных `json`, но ведь вопрос был про использование словарей:

```
import json
import os


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

        if os.path.exists(self.file_name):
            with open(self.file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                self.all_students = json.load(f)

        else:
            self.all_students = []

    def save(self):
        with open(self.file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(self.all_students, f, ensure_ascii=False)

    def get(self, num):
        return self.all_students[num - 1]

    def add_student(self, name, surname, age):
        self.all_students.append({"name": name, "surname": surname, "age": age})
        self.save()

    def select_by_age(self, age):
        return [x for x in self.all_students if x['age'] == age]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DataBase('all_students.json')

    print('''\
Выберите действие:
    1 - добавить студента,
    2 - вывод по номеру
    3 - вывод по возрасту,
    4 - вывод из файла
    для выхода - 0
''')

    while True:
        f = input('Ввод действия:  ')
        if f == '1':
            print('Введите данные через пробел (имя,фамилия,возраст)')
            name, surname, age = input().split()
            db.add_student(name, surname, age)

        elif f == '2':
            num = int(input('Номер ->  '))
            print(db.get(num))

        elif f == '3':
            items = db.select_by_age(input('Возраст-> '))
            print(items)

        elif f == '4':
            with open(db.file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                text = f.read()
                print(repr(text))

        else:
            break

    # Save file
    db.save()
```